# Is it correct to use 'looks'?

Tags: word-usage

In the followong sentence, I'm confused with the use of 'looks'. Is it grammatically correct?

> She looks an interesting girl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [that looks an interesting book; they look good guys](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/that-looks-an-interesting-book-they-look-good-guys) There might be a *slight* aversion in AmE (as opposed to BrE) to omitting the preposition with ***to look [like] something***, but I doubt anyone would suggest that it's somehow "incorrect".

Comment: It's also possible that the so-called expanded version uses *to be* rather than *like*: *She looks [to be] an interesting girl*. That would probably sound more natural if it were *she **seems** [to be] an interesting girl*, but the construction pattern is still the same.